# How to sort table columns in ascending or descending order by clicking the header

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sorting

I have a [store with items](http://www.twinkledreams.ca/teethers). Each item has a price.

I tried to sort them by ascending prices and descending by pricing the price header. When I click price all the items between $10 - $50 sorted correctly but anything less than $10 and above $50 doesn't sort with them.

Here is my code:

```
class TeethersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!,except: [:index,:show]
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  before_action :find_teether, only: [:destroy,:edit,:update,:show]

  def index
    @teethers= Teether.all.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
    @colors = Array.new
    @types = Array.new
    @teethers.each {|t| @types << t.types.pluck(:name) }
    @teethers.each {|t| @colors << t.colors.pluck(:name) }
    if params[:search]
      @search_term = params[:search]
      @teethers= @teethers.search_by(@search_term)
    end
    if params[:type_id]
      @types = Typation.where(type_id: params[:type_id])
      @teethers = @types.map(&:teether)
    end
  end

  def create
    @teether = Teether.new(teether_attributes)

    if @teether.save
      redirect_to teethers_path, notice: "Thank you... Your teether information was created successfully."
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Please correct the form"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @teether=Teether.new 
  end
  private
  def find_teether
    @teether = Teether.find(params[:id])
  end

  def sort_column
    Teether.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end

  def teether_attributes
    teether_attributes = params.require(:teether).permit([:name,:description,:price,:image,:keywords,:status,:quantity,:discount,:kind,{type_ids: []},:gender,:color,:theme])
  end
end
```

My application helper is:

```
module ApplicationHelper
   def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc")? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
  end
end
```

This is in my index:

```
<h3 id="sort"><label>Sort: </label><span> | </span><span><%= sortable "price" %><span class="caret"></span></span></h3>
```

In database

```
class CreateTeethers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :teethers do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.string :price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class AddDiscountToTeether < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :teethers, :discount, :text
    add_column :teethers, :kind, :text
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show your schema for teethers table?  It looks like it's sorting alphabetically, which makes me think "price" is a string?  Also (you've already noted this, I guess) you should really sort by the discounted price if available.

Comment: `if params[:search]` and `if params[:type_id]` are the problems, the `order` is gone when they these `if` are true.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages. Take the time to think up a much better title as it currently is poor.

Comment: We need more information. What is the schema for the table, and the smallest sample of prices that demonstrate the problem. Edit your question and add that information as if it'd been there all along. Don't use "edit" or "update" type tags as we can tell what changed. "[ask]" and its linked pages help explain.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I add the database in my question and yes the price is string. how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the price to decimal (or maybe integer... cents... and use "money" gem, it's a nice gem!).

I don't think a migration will let you change string to decimal but if this is a development that's not yet deployed and live, that shouldn't matter.

So, make a migration to remove_column 'value' and 'discount'

Then make a migration to add_column value as a decimal field, and discount as a decimal field.

Comment: Thank you so much it solved half of the problem. <%= sortable "money" %> how can I include discount money to this. so they can display with the discount price

Answer (score 3):

I checked out your website and I think your problem is that you are trying to sort price(string values) and this is causing problem. Let me try to explain it via this example.

```
arr = ['1', '45', '2', '100', '1001']
```

If you try to sort this array by this

```
arr.sort
```

it will give out this output ["1", "100", "1001", "2", "45"]

But if you use this kind of sort

```
arr.sort_by { |num| num.to_i }
```

it will give you something like this ["1", "2", "45", "100", "1001"]

In here depending on your preference you can use to_i, to_d or to_f methods

--------- After migration file is shared

You need to change text fields to decimal in your migration/schema.

```rb
class ChangeTeethersPriceAndDiscountToDecimal < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column :teethers, :price, :decimal
    change_column :teethers, :discount, :decimal
  end
end
```

After that your code is going to sort them correctly

Comment: But she doesn't use the Enumerable#sort.

Comment: I added a migration file to my answer. You can use it

Comment: Hi, Thank you its correct but Steve answered it before you :) I did up vote :)